# Disable Foundation Sticky on medium devices (tablets)

Tags: html, css

I have made a sticky sidebar with the help of foundation. Here is my code

```
<div class='row' id='top'>
  <div class='left'>{some nested divs}</div>
  <div class='right' data-sticky-container>
    <div class='sticky'
           data-sticky
           data-anchor='top'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `sticky` is located in the `right` class and he is its container while the anchor is `row` class.

It works fine on PC and it is automatically disabled on mobile which is great.

Here is my problem - if I open it on Ipad or any other tablet the  `sticky` leaves `right` and is on top of `left`.

I would prefer it if it could just be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroy by screen size

```
if (!Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast('medium')) {
  $('.sticky').foundation('_destroy');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was `data-sticky-on = 'large'` which disabled sticky on smaller devices